# I am building an app using Expo but for some reason all of a sudden the 'npm' start command no longer works

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I am fairly new to React Native. I am building a basic app using expo-cli. I don't have a deep understanding on how it works, but I've been following tutorials online on how to use it. Today, I was working on it and used 'npm start' command to launch the expo portal so I could demo my app on a virtual machine but it says it can no longer find the link to the .json file. Can someone please help me to get it working again.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're one directory up? Try `cd WhatsUp` and then run `npm start` again.